# Rails 2.3.x belongs_to association required by default?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In Rails 2.3.8, if I specify a relationship in my model as:

```
belongs_to :foo
```

Is that implicitly required now? If I want this model to always specify mymodel.foo when a new record is being validated, am I still required to use validates_presence_of :foo?

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not implicitly required; you need to validate the presence if needed.

Sometimes you want to have a `belongs_to` relationship where the `parent_id` is nullable, so these are treated as separate things.